# Record terminal output in python

Tags: python, terminal, output, capture

I am wondering if it is possible to capture the output of a terminal with python
an example output if I do not make sense:

```
person@computer:ls
    stuff stuff stuff
person@computer:python program.py
    person@computer:ls
    stuff stuff stuff
    person@computer:python program.py
```

Comment: There's `script(1)`, which does what you want?

Comment: By "capture" do you mean write the output to a file?

Answer (score 0):

I also agree with @Carpetsmoker.  Using 'script' will log the terminal screen for you, although it is a UNIX command and not a python script.  It can be invoked as such.

```
person@computer: script screen.log
-----Do some commands -----
person@computer: exit
```

Upon exiting there will be a text file (screen.log) generated in the directory that you invoked the script, which you can then review.  More info about script can be found here: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script

Comment: Here is a post which discusses alternatives for 'script' in Windows http://superuser.com/questions/325540/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-script-command-in-linux